# Upgraded to 4GB RAM, but only 2.93GB is usable. How do I fix this?

Tags: memory, upgrade, 32-bit

I upgraded my Lenovo G550 2983 32bit to Windows 10 and upgraded my RAM from 3GB to 4GB. I see the entire 4GB of RAM, but only 2.93GB is usable. This is the old 3GB RAM setting. Why didn't it update when I installed the new RAM? How can I fix it? It should show at least 3.5GB usable RAM.

Comment: Did you upgrade to the 64 bit version of Windows 10 or are you still running the 32 bit version? You can check by running the following command (in a cmd.exe prompt): `echo %processor_architecture%` You won't be able to address more than 3 gb of RAM until you upgrade to a 64 bit OS - see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier

Comment: Try going into BIOS and reduce the amount if memory set aside for video.

Comment: 32 bit Windows needs memory allocated for the graphics chip and kernel memory space. If you want to use the whole memory you will need to do a clean 64-bit install.